# Why does using large number of varargs in Kotlin var initalizion dramatically increases compile time?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on an Android project using Android Studio 4.1.2. The custom`MyPair` simply store two generic values while constructor of the `MySet` accepts any number of `MyPair`s:

```
// MyPair.kt
class MyPair<F, S>(one: F, two: S) {
    var first: F
    var second: S

    init {
         this.first = one
         this.second = two
    }
}


// MySet.kt
class MySet<K, V>(vararg pairs: MyPair<K, V>)

// Or MySet.java
public class MySet<K, V> {
    public MySet(MyPair<K, V>... pairs) {

    }
}
```

I am now trying to init a package level `MySet` instance with a large number of `MyPair`s:

```
package com.example.some.package

import com.examle.other.package.MyPair
import com.examle.other.package.MySet

var testSet: MySet<String, String> = MySet(
    MyPair("1", "one"),
    MyPair("2", "two"),
    MyPair("3", "three"),
    ...
    MyPair("n", "N"),
)
```

The larger the number of `MyPair` arguments, the longer the compile time. When passing 10 pairs the project takes about 30 Seconds to compile. When passing 30 pairs about 5 minutes.

The compile time also gets longer when using the Java version of `MySet` instead of the Kotlin implementation. When passing 30 pairs to the Java version compile time goes up to **20-30 minutes!**

**Why does the number of arguments effects compile time at all? Why so dramatically? Why is using a Java class so much slower?**

EDIT:

When using a static Java class instead of the Kontlin package var, everything works just fine. So there seems to be some kind of problem with Kotlin itself?

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-compile-so-slowly/1603/5 : might help it is known issue in kotlin for some time it compile some code very slow probably some gradel issue